# C++ Optimization Breaking Code That Stores References

Tags: c++, reference

I ran into an issue with my code that works fine without optimization, but breaks when optimization is enabled.  After much investigating, I found the point at which the code breaks.  It appears the problem has something to do with my use of references.

I have a simple class as follows:

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class DoubleValueEvent {
public:
    DoubleValueEvent(const T& v0, const U& v1) : _v0(v0), _v1(v1) {}
    //Move version of the constructor
    DoubleValueEvent(const T&& v0, const U&& v1) : _v0(v0), _v1(v1) {}

    inline const T& value0() const { return _v0; }
    inline const U& value1() const { return _v1; }

private:
    const T& _v0;
    const U& _v1;
};
```

My values (v0 and v1) are stored as references because, for my application, this object is acting as a wrapper around already existing variables and the lifetime of the object is only as long as the variables themselves.

Here's an example of how I am using it:

```
void myFunction(int a, bool b) {
    DoubleValueEvent<int,bool> e(a,b);
    
    //This functions uses e but never stores it
    foo(&e);
}
```

This has been working great and avoid unnecessary coping of data.  However, it breaks in the following case:

```
static inline int convert(int milliseconds) {
    return milliseconds / 1000;
}

void mySecondFunction(int a, bool b) {
    DoubleValueEvent<int,bool> e(convert(a),b);
    
    //Breakpoint here shows the stored value for the int to be garbage
    foo(&e);
}
```

If I put a breakpoint at the call to foo(), I can see that the value of the referenced stored in e is some garbage value and not what I would expect.

I surmise that what is happening is my constructor for DoubleValueEvent is not "moving" the temporary return value from convert() correctly and thus the compiler is optimizing this value out, but I am not sure.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: If optimizations break your code, it's likely that you have undefined behavior somewhere. Your references will never become dangling (where the objects they reference are destructed)?

Comment: Your constructor for `DoubleValueEvent ` does not move anything, not correctly not incorrectly, so you end up with dangling reference

Comment: `DoubleValueEvent(int index, const T&, U&&) = delete; DoubleValueEvent(int index, T&&, const U&)` might allow to spot the issue, (instead of your invalid attempt to handle r-value reference).

Comment: Code that breaks when using optimizations (not including language violating optimizations, of which gcc and clang have a few mostly around floating point) is also broken without optimizations, because **undefined behavior** can do anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're on the right track: your rvalue reference-taking constructor is not "moving" the value correctly. In fact, it's not moving it at all, in the sense of move-constructing a value from it.

Which makes sense. You haven't defined anywhere to move it *to*. Your class contains a couple of references, but nowhere to store them. After that line of code completes, what does the int *belong* to?

It seems like you're trying to benefit from some variant of the [Most Important Const](https://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/), where the lifetime of a temporary bound to a const reference persists for the lifetime of the object. But this only applies to locally scoped references, not references living in a class.

As you've said, "this object is acting as a wrapper around already existing variables". But in the problematic case, there are no variables for it to wrap, just expiring temporaries.

It's okay for a class to store lvalue references passed in to its constructor, but you need to be very, very careful with it. It is never okay for a class to store rvalue references passed in to its constructor, including storing them as lvalue references. The fact that it's an rvalue reference means that it's about to go away.

Comment: Okay, this makes sense.  So my question is, is there a way to modify my object to allow for temporaries in this way while still getting the benefits of not having to copy arguments to functions every time?  Or perhaps something I should modify for special cases like these?  I suppose one alternative would be to create a variable in my function to store the result of the convert() and then pass that to my DoubleValueEvent constructor.  That seems a bit messy though.

Comment: Sure. Just store `T` and `U`, not `T const&` and `U const&`. When needed, make a `DoubleValueEvent<Foo const&, Bar const&>`.

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best ones...  Or maybe most of the time... I think I will just go ahead and do that.